# Сидеть НА стуле, но В кресле

Tags: лингвистика

Мне вот подумалось, а почему мы сидим НА стуле, но В кресле? Если предположить, что дело в том, что мы погружаемся в мягкое кресло, то, например, диван или перина еще мягче, но мы сидим или лежим НА них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"НА", по сравнению с "В" - означает некоторую свободу, открытость. Сравните: *на поляне*, но *в лесу*.

Изначальное отличие кресла от стула в том, что у кресла есть подлокотники, а у стула нет. Соответственно на стуле, диване, табуретке необходимая для предлога "НА"  свобода есть, а в ограниченном кресле уже нет.

Comment: В кресле (внутри, на сидении). Свобода появляется, когда забираешься на спинку кресла :))) НА кресле можно сидеть и таким способом :))))))

Comment: Согласна. Плюс.

Comment: @Надюшка, кстати, да. Про то, что **на** спинке и подлокотнике кресла сидеть тоже можно подзабыл ))

Answer (score 2):

Различия между "В" и "НА" часто объясняется логикой, а традицией. 
Во сяком случае смотреть надо не сегодняшнюю ситуацию, а ту, что существовала на момент возникновения слова.
Общий принцип Вы уловили. "В" - внутри, "НА" - сверху. 
А вот с диваном - не совсем верно. 
Дело не в погружении в мягкую мебель (это совершенно необязательно), а в том, что кресло "охватывает" седока.

Вместе с тем в нацкорпусе есть огромное число примеров для "на кресле". Часть, правда, не относится к разбираемому случаю, но не стал их фильтровать, сути не меняет.

Насчет "свободы"... Почему работают на заводе, фабрике, на рынке, но в магазине, в школе, в театре, в депо?  На заводе свободнее? Не сказал бы )).

http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E0%20%EA%F0%E5%F1%EB%E5&p=10

Comment: Ну да. Из той же серии: спасть НА кровати, но В гамаке

Comment: Кстати, если кресло раскладное, но НА нем спят. Но можно вздремнуть и В кресле (сидя или полусидя/полулежа, короче говоря, под углом не 90*, а примерно 45 относительно горизонтали пола).

Comment: > Почему работают на заводе, фабрике, на
> рынке, но в магазине, в школе, в
> театре, в депо?

По той  же причине: свободы, открытости. И рынок, и завод, и фабрика в изначальном смысле - это территория с сооружениями для работы. А цех, магазин, школа, театр - это именно здания, поэтому требуют предлога "в".

Comment: Можно  "лежать на кровати", но "провести все утро в кровати". То же - "в постели". Второе, впрочем, точнее.

Comment: > А цех, магазин, школа, театр - это именно здания, поэтому требуют предлога "в".

И на театре, как на сцене света,
            Мы не выходим из балета:
                  Захочется ль кому
К честям и званиям пробить себе дорогу,
            Работы нет его уму —
           Умей он поднимать лишь ногу.
(Лермонтов)

Вот не читал Михаил Юрьевис Марка Иза.

Comment: Было бы наоборот, то **на** фабрику бы и не ходили, работали б люди **в** фабриках.

В театре, действительно, случай более запутанный, так как первые представления играли вне помещения, поэтому не исключаю существования во времена Лермонтова двух норм произношения. Хотя учитывая слабую отделку стиха (корявая последняя строчка), лучше поискать другой пример употребления.

Кстати, когда я работал **на** бетонном заводе, то если мне нужно было осмотреть оборудование в основном производственном здании, я шёл **в** завод и проверял.

Comment: Если Вам до сих пор непонятно, то Вы подгоняете объяснение под готовый ответ. 
И огромное число примеров из нацкорпуса - Вам не указ.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, подогнать объяснение под ответ - это на данный момент единственный эффективный способ решения задач возникновения чего-либо в незамкнутых системах, к которым относится и язык. В физике эту неизбежную подгонку называют, например,  антропным принципом.